# After HttpContext.SignOutAsync but User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is still true

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

After I run these two lines below, why `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is still true? How do I properly sign out?

```
await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

My project type is ASP.NET Core Razor Pages in .NET 6. Below is my `program.cs`

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

string[] initialScopes = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("DownstreamApi:Scopes")?.Split(' ');

builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
    .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

builder.Services.AddScoped<GraphProfileClient>();
    
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

Answer (score 3):

[HttpContext.User](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontext.user?view=aspnetcore-6.0) is not updated when you call HttpContext.SignOutAsync().

A user is only authenticated once per request. Once it  determines if they are authenticated or not, then it does not change for the remainder of that request.They are still authenticated for the duration of that request.

If you want  User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is  false, you can try to add below code after you call HttpContext.SignOutAsync():

```
 HttpContext.User = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(string.Empty), null);
```

From [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-6.0#sign-out) , we see:

> When the browser closes it automatically deletes session based cookies
> (non-persistent cookies), but no cookies are cleared when an
> individual tab is closed. The server is not notified of tab or browser
> close events.
>
> The user remains signed into the app as long as the authentication
> cookie is valid.

If you want cookie invalid after you sign out, you can read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-6.0#react-to-back-end-changes) to set  cookie validation.
Validating the cookie on every request mitigates the risk of revoked users accessing the app.

Comment: When the user click the logout, what is usually expected to clear?

Comment: @Steve From [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-6.0#sign-out) we can see "To sign out the current user and delete their cookie."

Comment: I did have `await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);` I think this could be due to I set remain login for the next 60 days?

Comment: @Steve If you configure Cookie ExpireTimeSpan, like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-6.0#add-cookie-authentication), it will set the cookie valid until your set time.